# Asp.Net / SignalR : Ajax Partial View

Tags: asp.net, ajax, asp.net-mvc-3, partial-views, signalr

I did a lot of research and testing with SignalR and I have an issue with it.

I'm creating a .Net MVC3 web application. The user interface is like this :

I'am not allowed to post images, so you can check the User Interface at this link :

http://deasign.free.fr/InterfaceVadis.jpeg

**The goal is :**

- User1 enter the Webapp, click on an Item, and see the Editing partial view.
- User2 enter the WebApp, click on the same Item. I want to LOCK the view for him.

Goal : Only one user at a time can edit an Item.

When the User1 leave the editing view by click previous/next/clicking on the list, logout or just close his browser the User2 had to receive instantly (via SignalR) a notification and the editing page is not locked Anymore

I have tried several thing but not achieved it.

1°) In which part do I have to declare the SignalR Hub ? In the Right Partial view or on the parent page ? I tried both but was unable to make the Disconnect function work as I want :(

I hope I've been clear, sorry for my English

If you need other information, don't hesitate

Thanks to all :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For all user operations such as previous/next/click etc, you could just call a function on the hub that would unlock the item:

JS:

```
$("#Next").click(function(e) {
  myHub.next();
});
```

CS:

```
public class MyHub : Hub {
  public void next() {
    var itemId = ClientManager.GetCurrentEditedItemForClient(Caller.id);
    ItemManager.UnlockItem(itemId);
  }

  public void previous() {
    var itemId = ClientManager.GetCurrentEditedItemForClient(Caller.id);
    ItemManager.UnlockItem(itemId);
  }
}
```

As for client leaving by closing, I know you can implement the IDisconnect interface and handle disconnects from there:

```
public class MyHub : Hub, IDisconnect {
    public void Disconnect()
    {
        var itemId = ClientManager.GetCurrentEditedItemForClient(Context.ClientId);
        ItemManager.UnlockItem(itemId);
    }
}
```

However, I also know that I haven't had much luck with the disconnect implementation. Maybe a routine that would check peridicaly the status of every client, or a pinger, anything. Someone else may have a better idea on this.

Comment: It's exactly what I've done, but like you I have issues with the IDisconnect Interface.



I need an advice : Where do you put the Hubconnection.Start ? On the MasterPage, on the Partial Views ? Sometimes when i look on the Firebug console I See that the hub connection is down

Comment: I would say that you have to put all this in the window.onload event first of all. Then, you may want to be contextual at some point (i.e.: connect to the hub only when needed). Either you have some way to check you are in the right context (if your hubs are in their own JS file using a bundler), or you start them in the partials. Have a look at the chat sample: https://github.com/kenegozi/SignalR-Chat